# wrong position of NSTextField in NSScrollView when its size change

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsscrollview

I have a simple `NSScrollView` created from IB.
I linked it from my .h file which is an `IBOutlet`:

```
IBOutlet NSScrollView *scroller;
```

In my .m, I insert programmatically an `NSTextField` like this:

```
NSTextField *dateTextField = [[NSTextField alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(30,yPos - kBreakHeight - 15, 100, kBreakHeight)];
[dateTextField setBordered:NO];
[dateTextField setEditable:NO];
[dateTextField setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
[dateTextField setAlignment:NSLeftTextAlignment];
[dateTextField setFont:[NSFont fontWithName:kAppFontBold size:11]];
[dateTextField setTextColor:[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:33/255.0 green:33/255.0 blue:33/255.0 alpha:1]];
[dateTextField setStringValue:dateString];
[[scroller documentView] addSubview:dateTextField];
```

unfortunately, at first lunch of my view, the text field is not at the right position (but the others elements in the documentView yes), and the position is correct only if I resize my window.

Any idea how to have the right position at launch?

Answer (score 0):

You don't state which version of OS X you are targeting, and if it is Lion, whether you use auto layout or traditional springs and struts.

If you use springs and struts (autoresizing masks), then you should just set a frame on the text field, before or after you add it.

If you use auto layout, you'll have to add the appropriate constraints after you have added the field. Oh, and remember to set the  `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property of the text field to `NO` before you add it - otherwise it will add its own constraints that will interfere with ones you add. In my experience it is much better to add your own explicit constraints than to rely on the auto generated ones.

There are some good docs on layout constraints here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/UserExperience/RNAutomaticLayout/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010631

And the WWDC session from last year really helps understand it (requires a password):

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=103

Comment: unfortunately, I don't use auto layout property... other views are correctly positioned then? Is it because it's come from IB components? For info, I'm working for a Lion release.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, just add...:

```
[dateTextField setAutoresizingMask:NSViewHeightSizable | NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewMaxXMargin | NSViewMaxYMargin | NSViewMinXMargin | NSViewMinYMargin];
```